# How to change pattern of HTML5 date input field?

Tags: html, date

The pattern of HTML5 input type date is mm/dd/yyyy on Chrome. How can I change this to mm/dd/yy?

Comment: The whole point of the native datepicker is that it uses the format the *user* wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Chrome's implementation reflects local user settings, but it seems Chrome always use four-digits year.